# How do I sum between check boxes in google sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, max, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet file that I'm using to collect data from boss drops in a game. Every once in awhile there is special loot. That special loot comes on average every 867,000 points. What I'm trying to do in the sheet is create a way to see how many points it has been since I received a special loot. A cell called "points dry".

The easy way is to just manually sum the points from the two checkboxes. `=sum(B26:B48)` or something like that. But I'd like to automate it so that it just sums between the last two checkboxes in column I. I'm pretty stumped on this and I don't know how to approach it.

Here are some screenshots from my spreadsheet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example? For instance, I can't see all the data in your screenshots, so, can you give a small example where you can easily say something like "from this dataset, the result should be ... because ..." and any other situations where the result should be different depending on specific conditions, if any?.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

> ...just sums between the last two checkboxes in column I

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(LARGE(IF(I:I=TRUE, ROW(I:I), ),  2)+1, 2, 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(  MAX(IF(I:I=TRUE, ROW(I:I), )), 2, 4))))
```

[image]